# AngularJS passing select values to ng-click function

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble figuring out how I am supposed to accomplish this task in angular. The  following code is wrapped in an `ng-repeat='item in items'`. I have left that out for simplification.

what I want to do is pass the value of my selects using the `addItem()` function. So when someone clicks the button they don't just pass the `item` but the values of the selects of this particular item as well. Perhaps the values of the options are passed as an array but I still wouldn't know how to accomplish that.

```
<div>
  <span class="balanced">$ {{item.price/100 | currency:''}}</span>
  <br/>
  <div ng-repeat="style in item.styles">
    <label class="input-label">{{style.style}}</label>
    <select>
      <option ng-repeat="option in style.options" value="{{option.option}}">
        {{option.option}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="button button-icon ion-plus" ng-click="addItem(item)">
    add
  </button>
</div>
```

Here is an example of what the data for `item` looks like.

```
{
   "productID": "4",
   "title": "Blouse",
   "description": "a nice blouse for any occasion",
   "price": "2000",
   "link": "http://productlink.com",
   "img": "http://imagelink.com",
   "styles": [{
     "style": "size",
     "options": [{
       "option": "9"
     }, {
       "option": "10"
     }, {
       "option": "11"
     }]
   }, {
     "style": "color",
     "options": [{
       "option": "red"
     }, {
       "option": "blue"
     }, {
       "option": "green"
     }]
   }]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First i would advice you to use the ng-options on the select instead of nesting ng-repeat inside select like this

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" 
ng-options="option.option for option in style.options" />
```

Then i would pass the selectedItem to your addItem function like this:

```
<button class="button button-icon ion-plus" ng-click="addItem(selectedItem)">
add
</button>
```

EDIT: You HAVE to change the ng-repeat (and remove the option tags). Use the ng-model together with ng-options on the select-tag. It's not a suggestion if you want it to work with ease. This way you remove the scope of the select and your selectedItem will be on the same scope (this case the entire controller - assuming your controller is the scope of the div you posted) as the button and the select tag.

EDIT: I think i finally understand what you want. One way to do it would be to keep track on your model (item) what options are selected. When you click the button some code will read the model and do whatever it needs to do. Since i don't know what you want to do with it, i created a simple plunker example that just writes the values in a div. You could pass that to a service/method to save it or whatever:

http://plnkr.co/edit/G0K6sU6GC92nEP3wKmQG

EDIT: Just wanted to add that you might want to save the options on a different object than your original `$scope.item`. You could change the the `ng-model` to `ng-model="myitem.selectedOption"` or something.

Comment: selectedItem is passed as 'undefined' in to my 'addItem()' function.

Comment: the problem seems to be that button is outside of 'ng-repaeat=" style in item.styles"' so that 'selectedItem' does not bind to the 'addItem(selectedItem)'. I can not put the button inside of that loop because I do not need multiple add buttons.

Comment: That is because you didn't change it like i wrote. Get rid of the ng-repeat and use ng-options instead. The scope of selectedItem will be that of the controller or other parent scope

Comment: You can use ng-change on your select to put your new selectedItem value into your item.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand ? If you call a function with ng-change that put selectedItem in your current style.options ?

Comment: There are multiple selectedItems - one for each select/dropdown and they are all supposed to get saved (only one button)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to initialize a `styleSelections` object and bind selection values with `ng-model`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="styleSelections={}">
  <span class="balanced">$ {{item.price/100 | currency:''}}</span>
  <br/>
  <div ng-repeat="style in item.styles">
    <label class="input-label">{{style.style}}</label>
    <select ng-model="styleSelections[style.style].choice">
      <option ng-repeat="option in style.options" value="{{option.option}}">
        {{option.option}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="button button-icon ion-plus"
          ng-click="addItem(item, styleSelections)">
    add
  </button>
</div>
```

The `ng-init` directive adds a property to the child scope of each item and the `ng-click` directive passes its value to the `addItem()` method in the controller.